# SVG filter not working in Safari

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari, svg-filters

On Safari 11.0, if I copy and paste the following code into the js console, I get the result shown in the image A, where the filter hasn't been applied to all elements.

However if I do the same thing on Chrome, I get the result shown in image B, the filter has been applied to all elements as expected.

Im simply adding an SVG filter that I want to apply to the whole HTML doc.

Any suggestions on why this is working on Chrome and not Safari?

```
var matrixValue = '0.299 0.587 0.114 0 0  0.299 0.587 0.114 0 0      0.299 0.587 0.114 0 0      0 0 0 1 0'; 

var div = document.createElement('div');  
div.innerHTML = "<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' version='1.1'><defs><filter id='ulSvgFilterDoc2'><feColorMatrix type='matrix' values='" + matrixValue + "'></feColorMatrix></filter></defs></svg>"; 

div.setAttribute('class', 'ulSvgFilterDoc'); 
div.setAttribute('id', 'ulSvgFilterDoc'); 
div.setAttribute('style', 'display: none;'); 
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].append(div); 
document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].setAttribute('style', 'filter: url("#ulSvgFilterDoc2")');
```

Image A: Safari
[image: SVG Color Filter - Safari]

Image B: Chrome
[image: SVG Color Filter = Chrome]

Comment: Interesting... I first thought it was because of `<g-XXX>` custom elements, but when [trying to reproduce](https://jsfiddle.net/67z7xc7e/), it works...

Comment: Is all the content coming from the same domain as the filter? There are cross-site restrictions in filters.

Comment: @MichaelMullany wouldn't these restrictions concern only the filter itself? Like you can't load cross-site filters, but you can apply it on any content. (And actually, since I am able to repro, I can tell for sure that targeting directly `g-XXX` elements with the same rule does work.)

Comment: I was a little rusty on this - you're right - you're not using any of the taintable primitives or inputs

Comment: Thanks, looks like this is a WebKit bug.